# how to run celery if i use fbone?

Tags: python, flask, celery

In my project structure is like [fbone](https://github.com/imwilsonxu/fbone), it means that I have following structure:

```
project: 
      app
           client
           api
           __init__.py  
           ..... 

      app_settings.py
      .....
```

in app_settings.py

```
    def create_app(config=None, app_name=None, blueprints=None):
        app = Flask('app', instance_relative_config=True)
        ...
        celery = make_celery(app)
        ...
        return app
```

and in `app.__init__.py`:

```
from app_settings import create_app
```

how to run celery worker in my case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution. We can create file, (manage.py):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from flask.ext.script import Manager
from extension import make_celery
from app import create_app

app = create_app()

celery = make_celery(app)
```

and than

```
celery -A manage.celery worker
```

Comment: Good that you found the solution! Do accept your answer